# How can a venv shared between machines use the exact same interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-venv

I have a directory accessible from multiple Linux machines on the same network (the precise terminology for this is a directory on a "mounted network drive", right?), within which I have a python virtual environment, made with `python3 -m venv venv`.

I've tried checking the python version from a few of the machines using this:

```
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ python --version
```

and I get back different versions depending on what machine it is. Some show `3.8.5`, some `3.8.10`. I believe I've figured out that this is because the "interpreter" in the venv is really a link to the interpreter in `/usr/bin`, which is machine-specific:

```
$ ls -lah ./venv/bin/ | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx  1 echols14 cs236ta    7 Sep 29 02:08 python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 echols14 cs236ta   16 Sep 29 02:08 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
```

When I take a look at the contents of `/usr/bin`, it seems like there are more things there relating to python than just the single interpreter file `python3.8`:

```
$ ls -lah /usr/bin | grep python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    2.3K Jun 20  2017 dh_python3-ply
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      23 Sep 28 16:10 pdb3.8 -> ../lib/python3.8/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      31 Mar 13  2020 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root       9 Mar 13  2020 python3 -> python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    5.3M Sep 28 16:10 python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      33 Sep 28 16:10 python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      16 Mar 13  2020 python3-config -> python3.8-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     364 Dec 17  2019 python3-qr
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    3.2K Sep 28 16:10 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      33 Mar 13  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
```

I'd like the venv to use the **same python version** regardless of which machine it is used from. Is that possible?

My first thought is to copy the `python3.8` file from one machine's `/usr/bin` and place it in the venv's bin, then adjust the links so that it is the one that gets used when the venv is activated. Would I need to copy other python-related files from `/usr/bin` for it to function? Is this method safe, or should it be avoided for some reason?

If that method is not a good idea, what other way could I get the shared venv to always use the same version of python, regardless of the machine?

NOTE: I don't have root/sudo permissions on all machines in question, but I do have root/sudo permissions on one of the machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. When creating the virtual environment, use the `--copies` option:

> --copies              Try to use copies rather than symlinks, even when
> symlinks are the default for the platform

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Which looks like this:

```
python3 -m venv --copies venv
```

And results in this:

```
$ ls -lah venv/bin/ | grep python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 echols14 cs236ta 5.3M Oct  7 18:26 python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 echols14 cs236ta 5.3M Oct  7 18:26 python3
```